# Merging two lists in F#

Tags: f#

I wrote this function which merges two lists together but as I'm fairly new to functional programming I was wondering whether there is a better (simpler) way to do it?

```
let a = ["a"; "b"; "c"]
let b = ["d"; "b"; "a"]

let merge a b =
    // take all a and add b
    List.fold (fun acc elem -> 
                     let alreadyContains = acc |> List.exists (fun item -> item = elem)
                     if alreadyContains = true then
                        acc
                     else 
                        elem :: acc |> List.rev
                     ) b a                

let test = merge a b
```

Expected result is: ["a"; "b"; "c"; "d"], I'm reverting the list in order to keep the original order. I thought I would be able to achieve the same using List.foldBack (and dropping List.rev) but it results in an error:

Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'a
but given a
    'a list
The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and ''a list'

Why is there a difference when using foldBack?

Comment: For foldBack, check the order of the parameters in the folder, it should be (fun elem acc -> ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I wanted to write this in a way that is similar to your original version (using `fold`), then the main change I would do is to move `List.rev` outside of the function (you are calling `List.rev` every time you add a new element, which is wrong if you're adding even number of elements!)

So, a solution very similar to yours would be:

```
let merge a b =
  (b, a) 
  ||> List.fold (fun acc elem -> 
        let alreadyContains = acc |> List.exists (fun item -> item = elem)
        if alreadyContains = true then acc
        else elem :: acc)   
  |> List.rev
```

This uses the double-pipe operator `||>` to pass two parameters to the `fold` function (this is not necessary, but I find it a bit nicer) and then passes the result to `List.rev`.

Answer (score 9):

You could use something like the following

```
let merge a b =
    a @ b
    |> Seq.distinct
    |> List.ofSeq
```

Note that this will preserve order and remove any duplicates.

In F# 4.0 this will be simplified to

```
let merge a b = a @ b |> List.distinct
```

Comment: Is it possible to include there a filter function ? If I had a list of records and wanted to compare by one of the properties?

Comment: Depending on how you want to filter, you could either pipe the result to List.filter, or use Seq.distinctBy